# Запрос к django серверу работает через раз

Tags: django, разработка-игр, unreal-engine-4

У меня есть сервер на django rest framework. Работает пока что на локальной сети через runserver. Пытаюсь общаться с ним через Unreal Engine и плагин VaRest. Запрос проходит, но все работает через раз. То есть, я нажимаю в игровом проекте кнопку, запрос проходит, все отлично. Нажимаю еще раз - ошибка. Третий раз нажимаю - снова все в порядке. Четвертый раз - ошибка, и т.д. Переменные Request и сам JSON запрос я очищаю в движке перед каждым запросом. Ошибка выходит вот такая:

```
[18/Feb/2020] code 400, message Bad HTTP/0.9 request type (':')
[18/Feb/2020] ": */*" 400 -
```

Заранее спасибо за ответы

Comment: 400 код - это код означающиц ошибку при валидации данных. Например, в теле post запроса ожидалось поле name, а его там нет. Тогда сервер отвечает 400 кодом. В любом случае телепатов тут нет... Будьте добры код viewSet и serializer в студию! А так же тело запроса, который отправляете, пожалуйста

Comment: @virvaldium спасибо за ответ, уже разобрался. Проблема была в самом запросе из движка. Нужно было не очищать его, а каждый раз создавать новый